My Confusion for Random Number Generator in C
I wanted to create a random number generator in C and basically what I wanted to do is rolling a dice every second and printing the results until I get 6. The code is down below.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){

    int dice;
    srand(time(0));
    
    do{
   


        dice = (rand() % 6) + 1;
        printf("%d\n", dice);


    }while(dice != 6);


    return 0;
}

At first I had an issue. The issue was, whenever I run the code it was spamming the same results until it gets to 6. But after I took srand(time(0)) command out of the loop, it seems to be solved. To be honest I had no idea while I was changing the code as I mentioned. Can someone explain how the time and srand functions work and how did I solve the issue?
